# Why has my reputation stopped increasing when I've been earning points for editing?

Tags: bug, editing, reputation, deleted-questions

My reputation stopped increasing at 1190 for the past 4 days, but I had been making edits that were approved, so I had earned reputation for edits during that time.

When I checked the next day however, my reputation had decreased back to 1190, though yesterday I also made 2 edits and earned 4 points. It indicated then that my reputation was 1194, but now my reputation is 1190 today and **none of my edited posts were removed**.

As of yesterday, my total number of edits was at 117, and it’s still 117 today, so I hope none of my edited posts were deleted.

Why it has been decreasing day-by-day and showing the same reputation score of 1190? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug. When posts are deleted, reputation points earned for editing them will be removed and your reputation will be recalculated shortly.

As indicated in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) Meta answer, users who created the post, users with specific high levels of reputation, moderators, and the system (aka., "Community") can delete posts. In fact, posts are automatically deleted by the system routinely according to the following:

6. [The system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) will automatically delete any post [flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work-in-stackoverflow) six times as offensive or spam.
7. The system will will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) closed (not as a duplicate), unlocked questions with zero or negative score having no upvoted or accepted answers or pending reopen votes, that were closed 9 or more days ago and haven't been edited in the past 9 days.
8. The system will automatically delete [unlocked, unanswered questions that have negative score after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).
9. The system will automatically delete [unlocked, unanswered questions with score of zero (or one if the owner is deleted), fewer than 1.5 views per day on average, and fewer than two comments after 365 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).
10. The system will automatically delete any question (and its answers) or answer with a score less than 0 when its owner's account is deleted.
11. The system will automatically delete questions migrated to other sites [after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/why-was-my-question-moved-and-why-was-it-then-deleted-off-of-the-original-site/79082#79082).

Unfortunately, because you were not the original poster, you won't be able to see the deleted posts. However, moderators and users with reputation greater than 10,000 can still see them, and looking at your reputation indicates that these posts were automatically deleted by Community (the system). Consequently the reputation points for editing them were also removed, and your reputation was recalculated accordingly.

Comment: Ok. Your Answer seems logical to me but my doubt was, If my edited post was deleted then it would also reflect in my overall edit count but as of yesterday my overall edit count was 117 and now also it's 117 and there was no decrease in count.

Comment: That number remains the same. However, you can also see the total number of edits that count towards badges by clicking on Review, then one of the links there (e.g., Suggested Edits), then hover over the number listed before the bar graph (before the Stats, History, and Review tabs).

Comment: I'm not able to click **Suggested Edits** since my reputation is below 2k.

Comment: Try any of the other links under the Review tab - the bar graph will be displayed there as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help @dan

Comment: No problem - it might prove informative for other users too.